# How to use an array of json value names to query from a json data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, json, vite

In react I would like to reuse this table I have created by calling this table with the interest (What I would like to show) and the json data if I map over the interest it gets all of the correct arrays also if I map over the data I also get correct data when I did in a static way of defining  `<TableCell align="right">{eq.id}</TableCell>` each of the points but in this case, I cant reuse this code with different API's that have completely different data names(interests). My issue is when I combine both data.interest ({eq.inter}) I get undefined.

```js
const {data} = useQuery(*API*)
var interest = ['id','name','age']
<DenseTable data={data} interest={interest}/>
```

```js
export default function DenseTable({ data, interest }) {
  return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Table sx={{ minWidth: 650 }} size="medium" aria-label="a dense table">
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            {interest.map((inter) => (
              <TableCell align="right">{inter}</TableCell>
            ))}
            <TableCell align="right">Edit</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Delete</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {data.map((eq, index) => (
            <TableRow key={index + "row"} sx={{ "&:last-child td, &:last-child th": { border: 0 } }}>
              {interest.map((inter) => {
                console.log(inter);
                return (
                  <TableCell key={eq.inter} align="right">
                    {eq.inter}
                  </TableCell>
                );
              })}
              <TableCell align="right">
                <EditIcon />
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">
                <DeleteIcon />
              </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/) (or _"json object names"_)

Comment: Edited the title is "JSON object value names" more understandable? Thanks.

Comment: Did you read the link or the site that it references? There's no such thing as a "JSON Object". It's either JSON (a string with a defined format) or something else (an object, a number, a string, ...)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Solved] needed to use eq[inter] instead of eq.inter